# Magento display configurable color's on category page

Tags: product, attributes, category

I have this code. It works great, get's the values.

```
<?php if($_product->isConfigurable()): ?>
  <?php $attributes = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributes($_product) ?>
  <?php if(count($attributes)): ?>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach($attributes as $att): ?>
      <?php $pAtt=$att->getProductAttribute();
        //get the child products
        $allProducts = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getUsedProducts(null, $_product);
        $frontValues =array() ?>
      <li><?php echo $pAtt->getFrontendLabel() ?>
       <ul>
       <?php foreach($allProducts as $p): ?>
         <?php if(!$p->isSaleable()) continue; ?>
         <?php $out=$p->getAttributeText($pAtt->getName()); ?>
         <?php $frontValues[$out]=$out; ?>
       <?php endforeach ?>
        <li><?php echo implode('</li><li>', $frontValues) ?></li>
       </ul>
      </li>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    </ul>
  <?php endif ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

But I don't want to see the Size option, just available colors and add ID to every `<li>` according to the color. For example:

The color is 251 in magento, so I want to add ID with a-Code (a-251) so I can target it with css easily.

Can you help me to modify a bit this code? Because I'm new, trying to modify it and getting errors.

Thanks,

UPDATE:

The code I have now:

```
                  <?php if($_product->isConfigurable()): ?>
                    <?php $attributes = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributes($_product) ?>
                    <?php if(count($attributes)): ?>
                      <div>
                      <?php foreach($attributes as $att): ?>
                        <?php $pAtt=$att->getProductAttribute();
                          if ($pAtt->getFrontendLabel() != 'Color') continue;
                          //get the child products
                          $allProducts = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getUsedProducts(null, $_product);
                          $frontValues =array() ?>
                        <div style="text-align:center;"><!--<?php echo $pAtt->getFrontendLabel() ?>-->
                         <ul>
                         <?php foreach($allProducts as $p): ?>
                           <?php if(!$p->isSaleable()) continue; ?>
                           <?php $out=$p->getAttributeText($pAtt->getName()); ?>
                           <?php $frontValues[$out]=$out; ?>
                           <?php $colors=$p->getData(strtolower($pAtt->getName()))?>
                         <?php endforeach ?>
                          <li><a id="a-<?php echo $colors ?>"><?php echo implode('</li><li>', $frontValues) ?></a></li>
                         </ul>
                        </div>
                      <?php endforeach ?>
                      </div>
                    <?php endif ?>
                  <?php endif ?>
```

I need to add the id in to the array, so it would add correct values (id's) to each color, can you help?

Answer (score 1):

Add after `$pAtt=$att->getProductAttribute();` line  `if ($pAtt->getFrontendLabel() != 'Color') continue;`

Actually it's not the best solution, but you can start with it and then optimize the code.

Comment: One more thing, how do I add id to every item? I have this in Layered, but this doesn't work here: `id="a-<?php echo $_item->getValueString() ?>'

Comment: Pls try `$pAtt->getId()`

Comment: This added a numeric vallue, but it doesn't match with the one I have in backend. For example: value for Black is 160, an getId, gets 92, any ideas? This is what i Mean: `<option value="160" selected="selected">Negro</option>` I want the final render to be `<a id="a-160">Negro</a>`

Comment: may be $p->getData(strtolower($pAtt->getName())) helps?

Comment: One small issue, how do I add it to array? Because now every color get's only the first value. Tryed to add:  `<?php $colors=$p->getData(strtolower($pAtt->getName()))?>` to foreach, and thant echo colors, but with no luck, ideas?

Comment: Any ideas? Can't get it to work for every item. Keeps adding the same value to all... :/

Comment: can you help me here, PLEASE!!!